# Restore old Windows XP behavior of ALT-TAB?

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I remember that some time ago (WinXP?) a simple **ALT-TAB** always and continuously switched back and forward between the last two windows.

Unfortunately now (Windows 7) this does not work anymore: Now, to continuously switch back and forward between the last two windows, requires me to first press **ALT-TAB**, then **ALT-TAB-TAB**, then again **ALT-TAB**, then **ALT-TAB-TAB**, etc.

This is annoying, because often instead of **ALT-TAB-TAB** I press **ALT-TAB** or vice versa.

Is there a way to go back to the old setting where I simply always had to press just **ALT-TAB** to continuously go back and forward between the last two windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a utility which gives me the exact desired behavior I described in my question:

VistaSwitcher

http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html

Answer (score 1):

Alt Tab always works for me.  And I have Windows 7.

You must have changed something to make it different.  Hard for a girl to guess what that might be.

Did you try system-restore and going back to before it changed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It changed a long time ago. Are you sure you have carefully read my question and completely understood its details?